# How do I select all categories per product and returning this in one row per product?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a bit of a brain freeze now, because this should be very easy (I think).

I have three tables:

- products list
- categories list
- category_map (links product and category)

I want to list products with its categories (names). One product may have many categories.

```
// This query
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.category
FROM sl_link_product_category c
LEFT JOIN sl_product a ON c.fk_productID = a.id
LEFT JOIN sl_category b ON c.fk_categoryID = b.id
WHERE c.fk_categoryID = b.id
ORDER BY a.id
```

```
// Gives me this result
| 1 | product 1 | cat 1 |  
| 1 | product 1 | cat 2 |  
| 1 | product 1 | cat 3 |  
| 2 | product 2 | cat 2 |
| 2 | product 2 | cat 4 |
```

Now, in the final result set, I want an array with products where each product has an array of categories.

My question is; Do I have to work with the result set in PHP to achieve my goal? Or is it possible in MySQL to put all categories (comma separated) in one variable / column?

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP_CONCAT` function is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.category)
FROM sl_link_product_category c
LEFT JOIN sl_product a ON c.fk_productID = a.id
LEFT JOIN sl_category b ON c.fk_categoryID = b.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
ORDER BY a.id
```